# How to open Bookmark Manager in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

How to open Bookmark Manager in Netbeans?

If it is any important I'm on Windows 10 using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 for PHP projets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the bookmark manager from **Windows > IDE Tools > Bookmarks**

https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb81/netbeans/develop/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG2300